# list all the permutation to sum up some numbers to a dest number

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to find which number in a list sum up to a certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420937/algorithm-to-find-which-number-in-a-list-sum-up-to-a-certain-number)

**question:**

there is a list: [1,2,3,4,6,8,10,12], i want to use these numbers to sum up to a new number 16.

**rules:**

1) don't need to use all of the numbers, 6 + 10 will be ok.

2) a number can use multi times, 12+2+1+1 will be ok.

3) order matters, 12 + 6 and 6 + 12 are two different combinations.

i have see [algorithm to sum up a list of numbers for all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403865/94962), but this is not the same.

don't know much about algorithm, if this fit certain algorithm, please let me know, or some python code / pseudo-code will be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, see [Find combinations of numbers that sum to some desired number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3363250/62576), [Algorithm to find which number in a list sum up to a certain number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3420937/62576), and [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4632322/62576), among others.

Comment: A number can be used multiple times _and_ order matters? Oh boy, look at all the combinations of `2+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1` you'll have to have.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for your link, i have read some, maybe i need to dig deeper

Comment: @TheZ yes, i know the result may be like ten thousands.

Comment: Since order matters perhaps you should refer to your "combinations" as permutations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First - note that even finding if there is any subset that sums to the desired number is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) and is known as the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), so there is no known polynomial solution for it.

Now, regarding the specific issue, here are some options:

First there is of course the obvious "generate all subsets and check the sum" way. Note that if your elements are all non-negative, you can use branch and bound and terminate a large portion of the possibilities before you actually develop them (If you found a subset `X` with `sum(X) == s`, and you are looking for the number `n < s` - you can be sure any set containing `X` will NOT find the solution). Something along the lines of:

```
findSubsets(list,sol,n):
  if (list.empty() and n == 0): #found a feasible subset!
     print sol 
     return
  else if (n < 0): #bounding non feasible solutions
     return 
  else if (list.empty()): #a solution that sums to a smaller number then n
     return
  e <- list.removeAndReturnFirst()
  sol <- sol.add(e)
  findSubsets(list,sol,n-e)
  sol <- sol.removeLast()
  findSubsets(list,sol,n)
  list.addFirst(e) #cleanup, return the list to original state
```

Invoke with `findSubsets(list,[],n)` where `list` is your list of items, `n` is the desired number and `[]` is an empty list.

Note that it can be easily parallelized if needed, there is no real syncrhonization needed between two subsets explored.

---

Another alternative if the list contains only integers is using [Dynamic Programming for solving the subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution). Once you have the matrix you can re-create all the elements from the table by going back in the table. [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7489398/572670) discusses how to get a list from the knapsack DP solution. The principles of the two problems are pretty much the same.