# Logically sorting integers data

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have following patterns of list available to play with.

```
Values : 
20,
25,
30,
35,
40,
45,
50,
55,
60,
70,
75,
80,
90,
100,
120
```

Next I have another set of values like these:

```
200,225,300,50,45,75, 15, 72
```

Now for the value `200`, I want the algorithm that to fetch possible values that might result it's sum in to a

```
LIST [100+100], [100+50+50], [50+50+50+50], [120+80]..
```

Similarly for `225`:

```
[25+120+80], [25+100+100], [100+45+80]..
```

and put it on another list.

exceptionally for `15`,

it can fetch `[20]`

for `72` it can fetch [70], [75]

Can any body help me to derive this logic?

Comment: `225: [25+120+80+100]`? I make that 325

Comment: What's the logic behind the two exceptions?

Comment: I am trying to iterate n x n times for the value such that the sum will be equal to 225 or the given value.

Comment: there is only one exception that belongs to same class.. [20] shows the minimum value that exist in the list while 72 shows possibility of any middle value;

Comment: This question is very unclear. what is the actual problem?

Comment: Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83547/algorithm-to-find-which-numbers-from-a-list-of-size-n-sum-to-another-number)

Comment: Sometime it's very difficult to ask what I want! in fact everytime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
var zs = ys.Select(y => Tuple.Create(y, xs.Subsets().Where(s => s.Sum() == y)));
```